# Webscraping with BeautifulSoup - How do I handle a "Load More" Button?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I build a webscraper with BeautifulSoup for the german yellow pages.

Works good so far.
However the problem is that there is a "Load More" Button which shows 10 more results. The URL does NOT change when clicking on it. Since I am a beginner and wrote the code with a YouTube Tutorial I really don't know how get my webscraper to get all results from the page.

Behaviour now:
Running the Webscraper gets me 50 results. After 50 results on the webpage there is a "Load More" button.

Expected Behaviour:
I can define how many times the webscraper "clicks" on the "Load More" button to get more results and safe them inside a list.

Obviously since the URL doesn't change I cannot add a {x} at the end of the link and do a loop. I also read something about Selenium but couldn't figure it out by myself.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main_list = []

def extract(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'x'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup.find_all('article', class_ = 'mod mod-Treffer')

def transform (articles):
    for item in articles:
        name = item.find('h2', {'data-wipe-name': 'Titel'}).text
        tel = item.find('p', class_ = 'mod-AdresseKompakt__phoneNumber').text
        try:
            website = item.find('a', class_ = 'contains-icon-homepage gc-btn gc-btn--s')['href']
        except:
            website = '' 

        business = {
            'Name': name,
            'Website': website,
            'Telefonnummer': tel, 
        }
        main_list.append(business)
    return

def load():
    df = pd.DataFrame(main_list)
    df.to_csv('stb_fürth.csv', index=False)

articles = extract(f'german yellow pages')
transform(articles)

load()

print('CSV Datei erstellt')
```

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Here is a search performed by me: https://www.gelbeseiten.de/Suche/Steuerberater/M%C3%BCnchen @AndrejKesely

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python-- webscraping for the content in "expand" button with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67820093/python-webscraping-for-the-content-in-expand-button-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: @newprogrammingdude If you want to get website and telephone number I'd suggest to open a new question here on SO.